# Integrating Facebook Connect with a Web Page

Tags: facebook

I have a web page that I want to integrate Facebook into. I want to display the "Connect with Facebook" button (note: NOT the "Login with Facebook" button). For the life of me, I cannot find any documentation on the Facebook developer site regarding this.

Has the "Connect with Facebook" button been deprecated? I have used it before. I can't find any information regarding it. Does anyone have any information about this?

Comment: What's the difference between two?

Comment: If you just want to enable user to be registered to your website without creating yet another username, then "Login with Facebook" is the same, I think

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Facebook Connect has been deprecated but you can find documentation on what to use on http://developers.facebook.com

Answer (score 0):

I am using Facebook Connect on my site, and it still works, but I would recommend against it as all documentation on it has vanished from the web.

These links might be helpful:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/connect_auth/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/oauth2-https-migration/