# Facebook Connect vs facebook-android-sdk on Android

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I am trying to add a social aspect to my app where one can post there results (a common feature).

I have found some sites that describe how to do this using Facebook Connect http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/android/845/

and others, like the Facebook developer site point you towards using the SDK and downloading through Github. 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/

Anyone have any experience with this?  What is the difference between the two options and which is better for apps?

All the other questions that seem relevant are years old.

Comment: What is your question? Which is better?

Comment: What is the difference between the two, which is the best to use for a mobile app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the Facebook-Android-SDK for a couple reasons.

1. It comes from Facebook themseleves. ...Perhaps this is actually a reason not to use it! :)
2. It uses OAuth for authentication, which is good, and it is pretty easy to use.
3. The Graph API.  It is pretty robust, and also easy to use.

Please note that I have *not* used FB-Connect before, so I may be a bit biased...

Answer (score 0):

Facebook Connect has been deprecated and you should use the SDK - [Integrating Facebook Connect with a Web Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558686/integrating-facebook-connect-with-a-web-page)

Answer (score 0):

I have familiary with the [facebook-android-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/commits/master) I've never had a problem with it and it seems to work very well.

It doesn't really make sense not to use the native SDK unless you are using a webapp imo.

Also I think FBConnect has been deprecated.